# Integers whose arithmetic mean equals their geometric mean

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

For which positive integers *n* is it possible to find *n* integers whose arithmetic mean equals their geometric mean?

Comment: The solutions form an $(n - 1)$-dimensional hypersurface in the $n$-dimensional affine space, hence it is quite reasonable to believe that such integers exist for all $n$.

Comment: I guess you mean to ask for $n$ *distinct* integers, such that its arithmetic mean equals its geometric mean. Without the distinctness requirement it becomes trivial. (Just take them all to be 1.)

Comment: @Nathaniel The question asks for "n integers", not "a multiset of integers with size n".

Comment: @Sneftel the question doesn't specify whether it should be a set or a multiset or a list - it just says "n integers". Since normally the arithmetic or geometric mean would be applied to a list rather than a set, it seems not unreasonable to mention the distinctness requirement.

Comment: @Nathaniel If a question asked for three words which started with "A", would you respond "apple, apple, and apple"?

Comment: @Sneftel it very much depends on context. I can certainly imagine a puzzle where that would be the intended solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for a truly fun puzzle whose specific solutions feel like
individual adventures, @María Lucía Uribe, and for appreciating my answer.
Yet i would not mind at all, quite the opposite, if you were to
transfer the $\color{#0c0}{\Large\raise-.1ex\checkmark}\kern-.2em$ to
[Paul Panzer’s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/103852/).
That delightfully resourceful solution is what i had originally hoped
mine to become: complete and deterministic/prescriptive.
(I'm quite happy anyway with the gallery that my answer became.)
Thanks again

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that only the *count* of integers, *n*, is stipulated as positive
whereas the numbers whose means are sought are specified as just *integers*.
This allows negative numbers to be included among those being averaged.

Variations of a straightforward, though only sometimes truly deterministic,
approach seem able to produce any $\small n \,{\ge}\, 3$
distinct non-zero integers whose arithmetic and geometric means are equal.
Characteristic of this approach are the patterns
of exponents and positive–negative number pairs
in these examples.

> 3 integers:     $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   27,    \, -8,    \, -1                 \raise-2ex\strut  $
>  
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ 27 \, - \, 8 \, - \, 1 \over 3}} \,=~ 6 \raise-3ex\strut $
>  
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\Large \raise.1ex 3 \!\:} \of { \, (3^3) \, (-2^3) \, (-1) } \,=~ 3 \cdot 2 ~=~ 6 \raise-6ex\strut $
>  
>  4 integers:     $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   27,    \, -3,   ~~   4,    \, -4                                                   \raise-2ex\strut  $
>  
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ 27 \, - \, 3 \, + \, 4 \, - \, 4 \over 4}} \,=\, {\large{ 24 ~+~ 0 \over 4}} \,=~ 6 \raise-3ex\strut $
>  
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\Large \raise.1ex 4 \!\:} \of { \, (3^3) \, (-3) \, (2^2) \, (-2^2) } \,=~ 3 \cdot 2 ~=~ 6 \raise-6ex\strut $
>  
>  5 integers:     $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   27,   ~~   6,    \, -3,   ~~   4,    \, -4                                                   \raise-2ex\strut   $
>  
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ 27 \, + \, 6 \, - \, 3 \, + \, 4 \, - \, 4 \over 5}} \,=\, {\large{ 30 ~+~ 0 \over 5}} \,=~ 6 \raise-3ex\strut  $
>  
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\large \raise.1ex 5 \!\:} \of { \, (3^3) \, (3 \cdot 2) \, (-3) \, (2^2) \, (-2^2) } \,=~ 3 \cdot 2 ~=~ 6 \raise-6ex\strut $
>  
>  6 integers:     $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   81,   ~~   9,   ~~   125,    \, -125,   ~~   1,    \, -1                                                    \raise-2ex\strut  $
>  
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ 81 \, + \, 9 \, + \, 125 \, - \, 125 \, + \, 1 \, - \, 1 \over 6}} \,=\, {\large{ 90 ~+~ 0 \over 6}} \,=~ 15 \raise-3ex\strut $
>  
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\large \raise.1ex 6 \!\:} \of { \, (3^4) \, (3^2) \, (5^3) \, (-5^3) \, (1) \, (-1) } \,=~ 3 \cdot 5 ~=~ 15  \raise-6ex\strut $
>  
>  7 integers:     $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   75,   ~~   25,   ~~   5, ~{\pm}\,135, ~{\pm}\,1 \raise-2ex\strut  $
>  
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ 75 \, + \, 25 \, + \, 5 ~+~ 0 \over 7}} \,=~ 15  \raise-3ex\strut $
>  
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\large \raise.1ex 7 \!\:} \of { \, (\,5^2 {\cdot\!\;} 3) \, (5^2) \, (5) \, (-5^2{\cdot\!\;}3^6) \, (-1) } \,=~ 5 \cdot 3 ~=~ 15 \raise-6ex\strut $
>  
>  8 integers:     $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   125,    \, -5, ~{\pm}\,5^2, ~{\pm}\,3^3, ~{\pm}\,3 \raise-2ex\strut  $
>  
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ 125 \, - \, 5 ~+~ 0 \over 8}} \,=~ 15               \raise-3ex\strut $
>  
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\large \raise.1ex 8 \!\:} \of { \, (5^3) \, (-5) \, (-5^4) \, (-3^6) \, (-3^2) } \,=~ 5 \cdot 3 ~=~ 15 \raise-6ex\strut $
>  
>  9 integers:     $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   54, ~{\pm}\,2^4, ~{\pm}\,3^2, ~{\pm}\,3, ~{\pm}\,1 \raise-2ex\strut  $
>  
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ 54 ~+~ 0 \over 9}} \,=~ 6                           \raise-3ex\strut $
>  
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\large \raise.1ex 9 \!\:} \of { \, (2 \cdot 3^3) \, (-2^8) \, (-3^4) \, (-3^2) \, (-1) } \,=~ 2 \cdot 3 ~=~ 6 \raise-6ex\strut $
>  
>  10 integers:    $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~     243,   ~~   27, ~{\pm}\,3, ~{\pm}\,9^3, ~{\pm}\,9^2, ~{\pm}\,1 \raise-2ex\strut  $
>  
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ 243 \, + \, 27 ~+~ 0 \over 10}} \,=~ 27                         \raise-3ex\strut $
>  
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\large \raise.1ex 10 \!\:} \of { \, (3^5) \, (3^3) \, (-3^2) \, (-9^6) \, (-9^4) \, (-1) } \,=~ 3 \cdot 9 ~=~ 27 \raise-6ex\strut $
>  
>  12 integers:    $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~     125,    \, -5, ~{\pm}\,5^4, ~{\pm}\,2^3, ~{\pm}\,2^2, ~{\pm}\,2, ~{\pm}\,1 \raise-2ex\strut  $
>  
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ 125 \, - \, 5 ~+~ 0 \over 12}} \,=~ 10                                      \raise-3ex\strut $
>  
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\large \raise.1ex 12 \!\:} \of { \, (5^3) \, (-5) \, (-5^8) \, (-2^6) \, (-2^4) \, (-2^2) \, (-1) } \,=~ 5 \cdot 2 ~=~ 10 $

Variations of the present approach work predictably
on three categories of group size $\small n$.

• Even group sizes $          \raise1ex\strut
                             \kern2.5em \small~  n\,=\,    4m ~~~~~~~\ge~~~ 4 $.

• Even group sizes $ \kern2.5em \small~ n \,=\,   4m+2     ~~\ge~~ 6 $.

• Odd square group sizes $       \small~n  \,=\, (2m{+}1)^2  ~\ge~ 9 $,
 which allow for a truly deterministic recipe.$ \raise-1ex\strut $

*Ad hoc* application of this approach
seems to work consistently but unpredictably
on the remaining category of group size.

• General odd group sizes $\raise1ex\strut\small~n\,=\, 2m+1 ~\ge~ 3
                                                             \raise-1ex\strut $.

**Deterministic recipe for an
$\small\boldsymbol{n \,{=}\, (2m{+}1)^2}$
odd square group size**

The present approach is well exemplified in producing a group
of $\small n \,{=}\, (2m{+}1)^2 {=}\, 9$ distinct non-zero numbers,
where $ \small h \,{=}\,  {\large{n-1 \over 2}}
                       \,{=}\, 4 \Large\strut $.
An odd square group size allows a deterministic recipe to
produce exceptionally tidy calculations.

> 9 integers:       $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (\surd n)^3(1{+}\surd n)(2{+}\surd n) \, , ~~~{\pm}\,(\surd n)^{h-1} \, , ~~~{\pm}\,(1{+}\surd n)^h \, , ~~~{\pm}\,(2{+}\surd n)^h \, , ~~~{\pm}\,1 \raise-4ex\strut  $
>
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ (\surd n)^3(1{+}\surd n)(2{+}\surd n) ~+~ 0 \over n}} \,=~ (\surd n)(1{+}\surd n)(2{+}\surd n) \raise-5ex\strut $
>
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\large \raise.1ex n \!\:} \of { \, (\surd n)^3(1{+}\surd n)(2{+}\surd n) ~ {\large(}\!\!\!\: -\!(\surd n)^{2h-2} {\large)} ~ {\large(}\!\!\!\: -\!(1{+}\surd n)^{2h} {\large)} ~ {\large(}\!\!\!\: -\!(2{+}\surd n)^{2h} {\large)} ~ (-1) \tiny\raise3ex\strut } \raise-4ex\strut $
>
>  $\kern6em\small ~=~ \root{\large \raise.1ex n \!\:} \of { \, (\surd n)^n (1{+}\surd n)^n (2{+}\surd n)^n } \raise-3ex\strut $
>
>  $\kern6em\small ~=~ (\surd n)(1{+}\surd n)(2{+}\surd n) $
>
> Explicitly: $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 3^3 {\!\!\;\cdot\!\:} 4 {\!\:\cdot\!\:} 5 \!\; , ~{\pm}\,3^3 \!\!\; , ~{\pm}\,4^4 \!\!\; , ~{\pm}\,5^4 \!\!\; , ~{\pm}\,1 \raise-3ex\strut  $
>
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ 3^3 {\!\!\;\cdot\!\:} 4 {\!\:\cdot\!\:} 5 ~+~ 0 \over 9}} \,=~ 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 ~=~ 60 \raise-4ex\strut $
>
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\large \raise.1ex 9 \!\:} \of { \, ( 3^3 {\!\!\;\cdot\!\:} 4 {\!\:\cdot\!\:} 5) \, (-3^6) \, (-4^8) \, (-5^8) \, (-1) } \raise-3ex\strut $
>
>  $\kern6em\small ~=~ \root{\large \raise.1ex 9 \!\:} \of { \, (3^9)(4^9)(5^9) } \,=~ 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 ~=~ 60 $

This recipe has features that simplify calculation
enough to make the following advantages self evident.

- The geometric mean is an integer as all the terms
  under the radical are powers of 3, 4 and 5
  while exponents of each 3, 4 and 5
  add up to $\small n \,{=}\, 9$.
- The arithmetic mean’s numerator reduces to one term
  as all those positive–negative number pairs cancel to zero.
  This is possible because $\small n \,{=}\, 9$ is odd.
- That remaining arithmetic-mean term,
  $\small 3^3 {\!\!\;\cdot\!\:} 4 {\!\:\cdot\!\:} 5 $,
  includes odd powers of 3, 4 and 5 each,
  again because $\small n \,{=}\, 9$ is odd.
  Dividing by   $\small n$
  leaves a product of $\small 3^1$, $\small 4^1$ and $\small 5^1$,
  which matches the geometric mean.
  Only because $\small n \,{=}\, 9 \,{=}\, 3^2$ is an even power of
  3 — a square — can
  dividing an odd power of 3 by it leave $\small 3^1$.

Those beneficial features were the goals that led to the solutions here.
Note that the 9-number solution listed at the top of this answer
differs from the recipe used just now.
It has just two basis factors, 3 and 2, rather than three.
This works because powers of just two factors
may be distributed nondeterministically among 9 numbers
so that the exponents of each factor add to 9,
maintaining a simple geometric mean calculation.
Thus the door opens to nondeterministic approaches for
even group sizes $\small 4m$ and $\small 4m{+}2$.

**Nondeterministic straightforward approach for an
$\small\boldsymbol{n \,{=}\, 4m}$ even group size**

With an even count of numbers,
positive–negative number pairs leave
two uncanceled terms in the arithmetic mean.
A good example is the case of $\small n \,{=}\, 4m \,{=}\, 8$ numbers,
this time with two factors to be determined,
$\small i$ and $\small j$.

> 8 integers:     $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   i^3 \!\!\; , \, -i \!\; , ~{\pm}\,i^2 \!\!\; , ~{\pm}\, j^3 \!\!\; , ~{\pm}\, j \raise-2ex\strut  $
>
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ i^3   \,  -  \,  i ~+~ 0 \over 8}} ~=~ {\large{ i \, (i+1)(i-1) \over 8}}        \raise-3ex\strut $
>
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\large \raise.1ex 8 \!\:} \of { \, (i^3) \, (-i) \, (-i^4) \, (-j^6) \, (-j^2) } \,=~ i \, j $

Exponents of $\small i^3$ and $\small -i$
were chosen to produce an easy equation to solve.
Exponents of the positive–negative number pairs, however,
need only to produce distinct values.
The easy equation to solve comes from
equating the two means and eliminating a common
factor of $\small i$.

$ \kern9em\small (i{+}1)(i{-}1) ~ = ~ 8 \, j $

Among infinitely many easy solutions,
one that can be directly read out is
$\small i{+}1 \,{=}\, 8$ and $\small i{-}1 \,{=}\, j$, giving
$ \small i \,{=}\, 7$ and $\small j \,{=}\, 6$.

> 8 integers:     $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   7^3 \!\!\; , \, -7 \!\: , ~{\pm}\,7^2 \!\!\; , ~{\pm}\,6^3 \!\!\; , ~{\pm}\,6 \raise-2ex\strut  $
>
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ 7^3  \, - \, 7 ~+~ 0 \over 8}} \,=\,  {\large{ 336 \over 8}} \,=~ 42          \raise-3ex\strut $
>
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\large \raise.1ex 8 \!\:} \of { \, (7^3) \, (-7) \, (-7^4) \, (-6^6) \, (-6^2) } \,=~ 7 \cdot 6 ~=~ 42 $

**Nondeterministic straightforward approach for an
$\small\boldsymbol{n \,{=}\, 4m{+}2}$ even group size**

This is essentially the same as for $\small n \,{=}\, 4m$ group size
except that the two single-signed terms are $\small i^4$ and $\small i^2$,
leading to another easy equation to solve.

$ \kern9em\small i \, (i^2{+}1) ~ = ~ n \, j $

**Nondeterministic unpredictable approach for a general
$\small\boldsymbol{n \,{=}\, 2m{+}1}$ odd group size**

These group sizes are the most fun as each non-square-count
feels like a brand new adventure that leads to solution
via a creative combination of moves hinted by previous solutions.
Here, for example, is how $\small n \,{=}\, 5$ played out.

> 5 integers:     $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   i^3 \!\!\; , ~\, i \!\!\; j \!\; , \, -i \!\; , ~{\pm}\,j^2 $   (notice the $\small i \!\!\; j \raise-2ex\strut$)
>
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ i^3 + \, i \!\!\; j \, - \, i ~+~ 0 \over 5}} ~=~ {\large{ i \, (i^2+j-1) \over 5}}        \raise-3ex\strut $
>
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\large \raise.1ex 5 \!\:} \of { \, (i^3) \, (i \!\!\; j) \, (-i) \, (-j^4) } \,=~ i \, j $

This does lead to yet another readily solved equation
although, admittedly, the choice of
$\small i^3$, $\small i \!\!\; j$ and $\small -i$
wasn’t the first combination of single-sign numbers attempted
as other combinations led to unsolvable equations.

$ \kern9em\small i^2 \, = ~ 4 j \,{+}\, 1 $

The values $\small i \,{=}\, 3$ and $\small j \,{=}\, 2$
produce the solution for $\small n \,{=}\, 5$ numbers
listed at the top of this answer.

**Solution initially posted with this answer**

The solution posted at first
has $\small n \,{=}\, 3$ non-zero integers
of which two are the same.

> 3 integers:     $\small~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   8,    \, -1,    \, -1                 \raise-2ex\strut  $   (−1 is repeated)
>
>  arithmetic mean = $\small~ {\large{ 8 \, - \, 1 \, - \, 1 \over 3}} \,=~ 2 \raise-3ex\strut $
>
>  geometric mean =  $\small~ \root{\Large \raise.1ex 3} \of { \, (8) \, (-1) \, (-1) } \,=~ 2 $

This initial solution was found on a hunch,
based on familiarity with the coincidental
arithmetic and geometric subsequence properties
of $\small \{ -2, \, 1, \, 4 \, \}$.
It seemed easiest to experiment with
$\small \{ \, {\normalsize i^{\!\; 3}} \! , \, -1, \, -1 \, \}$,
as its geometric mean is simply $i$,
and the present solution leapt out.

**Note from comments**

Paul Panzer points out that infinitely many easily produced
distinct-integers solutions exist for all n ≥ 3
if the number 0 is brought into play.

> Constructing zero mean sequences of any length is pretty much trivial
> even if you require all numbers to be distinct
> (*n* = 2 being the only exception).
> –
> [$\small\color{#3366ff}{\textsf{Paul Panzer}}$](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70634/paul-panzer)
> [$\small\color{#8888ff}{\textsf{Oct 13 '20 at 1:24}}$](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102840/integers-whose-arithmetic-mean-equals-their-geometric-mean#comment293271_103844)

Comment: Nice observation of the hole in the problem statement.

Comment: @Bubbler speaking of holes in the problem statement it also doesn't say that the numbers have to be distinct. So if you want to take a "legalistic" approach that's much easier to exploit ;-)

Comment: @humn IF you allow negarives it would appear to make no sense to exclude 0 as the mean. Constructing zero mean sequences of any length is pretty much trivial even if you require all numbers to be distinct (n=2 being the only exception).

Comment: I went ahead an added your comment to this answer, @Paul Panzer, thank you. Please feel free to edit (or undo) or move it to an answer of yours.

Comment: @humn: Personally, I would have said that the simplest would be to just multiply all numbers by a contant value. This works on any solution to give another solution (since that constant can basically be factored out right at the beginning of the calculations)!

Comment: Indeed, @Chris, it doesn't get simpler than scaling. I'll refrain from making the claim and mention variability in a different place and manner.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath indeed for me no answer seems complete, a correct answer should give the formula to enumerate all possible values of _n_, and prove that other values are not possible.

Comment: Apologies for pointing out the obvious but if you can do every even number, you can also do at least every other odd  number: For any even solution add the average itself. Or, if it is already in the list remove it. (I'm not sure whether it is possible for the mean to be non-integer but as it is the arithmetic mean of integers this can in any case be fixed by scaling.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what is suddenly _now_ obvious, @Paul Panzer.
Your extension to odd $\small 2m{+}1$ will work every time
for the way i've routinized even $\small 2m$.
By happenstance my examples for
$\small n{=}4$ and $\small n{=}5$ already demonstrate it.
Sure wish i'd thought
of it myself but at least this puzzle has already been fun.

Comment: I don't think your use of "deterministic" is quite right.

Comment: Does my intended meaning of "deterministic"
come across anyway, @Acccumulation ,
or would something like "prescriptive" be better?
What i mean is that getting a result
doesn't involve making choices along the way.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a method for constructing nonzero duplicate-free solutions for any N>2:

Preamble N=2:

> Not possible because $\sqrt{XY}=\frac{X+Y} 2$ implies $4XY=(X+Y)^2$ implies $X=Y$

> First, observe that you can amalgamate solutions $\{a_i\}_{1...N}$,$\{b_j\}_{1...M}$ by

1. Multiplicative amalgamation (resulting size $N=N_1\times N_2$):

> form their outer product $c_{ij} = a_ib_j$. This has the required property because $\sum c_{ij} / NM = \sum a_i / N \times \sum b_j / M = \prod a_i^{1/N} \times \prod b_j^{1/M} = \prod c_{ij}^{1/NM}$

2. Additive amalgamation (resulting size $N=N_1 + N_2$):

> Multiply each with the mean of the other (as the mean is both arithmetic and geometric it must be integer). Now we can simply concatenate: $c_k = \overline{b}a_i$ if $k\le N$ else $\overline{a}b_{k-N}$

3. Small N (=3) factory:

> Therefore all we need is a factory for small solutions. It has to be able to produce multiple (infinitely many) substantially different solutions because otherwise we cannot rule out that amalgamation produces some non-unique terms. (Demonstrating this cleanly is rather technical, so I'll skip that for the moment.)

> We can generalize @Bubbler's formula: $(X+Y)^3,-X^3,-Y^3$ (*)
>  
>  With this and additive amalgamation we can do all multiples of 3

3b. N not a multiple of 3:

> If $N\equiv 1\mod 3$ we can construct the $N-1$ solution and append the mean.
>  If $N\equiv 2\mod 3$ we can use @humn's 5 terms solution and amalgamate with the appropriate 3n solution.

Conservation of uniqueness under additive amalgamation:

> For that it suffices to observe that for each element its quotient with the mean is preserved. Thus if we can demonstrate that these ratios can be kept unique in (*) we are done. These ratios are $\frac{(X+Y)^2}{XY}$, $-\frac{X^2}{Y(X+Y)}$ and $-\frac{Y^2}{X(X+Y)}$.
>  
>  Therefore a simple strategy would be making all $X$ and all $Y$ relatively prime,

5. Example:

> 12 unique terms from additively amalgamating (*) for $X,Y = (3,4); (6,7); (9,10); (12,13)$:  $6951106562400,-610248038400,-1191890700000,6895939050000,-700831731600,-1046139494400,6880893364800,-742996800000,-988928740800,6874720776000,-767350584000,-958402368000$
>  
>  Mean: $1716322608000$

Comment: Wow, that's an extreme generality.

Comment: Great solution; You might want to incorporate the (not that difficult) proof that any choice of distinct (non generalized) scaled Bubbler's triplets contains only different values and not the mean

Comment: You wuz robbed of the $\color{#0c0}{\Large\raise-.1ex\checkmark}\kern-.5em$,
$\,$Paul Panzer, i'm guessing only because of timestamps.
You already know many of the reasons i look up to this solution
and i'll figure out an appropriate way to assure this puzzle's poser
that it's never too late to change an acceptance.
Signed, someone who'z been at all corners of this kind of thing
and feels worst 1) even when _credibly_ beating out a favorite fellow solver
by a millijiffy (no more sprints for me) and 2) in the present corner.

Comment: No worries, @humn, I don't feel aggrieved in any way.

Answer (score 6):

No one said [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers), so I went ahead with Z3 code to find a solution of three nonzero, distinct integers.

```
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(declare-const c Int)
(assert (< 0 a))
(assert (> 0 b))
(assert (> 0 c))
(assert (>= 27 a))
(assert (<= -27 b))
(assert (<= -27 c))
(assert (distinct a b c))
(assert (= (* 27 a b c) (^ (+ a b c) 3)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7BCsIwDAbgu0@RY6sUZDt4Wb37EkKaBh3ODpacfPm6jgl27Jgv@cP/aXM2kWnAiR2NSRQQbkntYaNhV2lVFOFJwXRwBrR/cJ0hbIEq8NBc6lDnwc0WdqyKxl60T1Qqh3rjwRyXt8sCzB3M6Te0tlzSk@nlBEv7B6t7j5EHm/MX)

Then it found $a=27, b=-1, c=-8$ which gives the arithmetic and geometric mean of $6$.

After that, I found that a general formula of $a=(x+1)^3, b=-x^3, c=-1$ works (and the numbers are distinct when $x\ge 2$):

$$
\frac{a+b+c}{3} = \frac{(x+1)^3 - x^3 - 1}{3} = \frac{3x^2 + 3x}{3} = x^2 + x \\
\sqrt[3]{abc} = \sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3 x^3} = (x+1)x = x^2 + x
$$

I'm not sure if a similar pattern can be found for higher $n$.

Comment: Wow, @Bubbler!  Great to see an interesting new language too.  Also would be interesting to see how non-computer you got to that wonderful general formula.  Would it be safe to edit your program (and not save!) for my larger-_n_ hunches?

Comment: @humn Sure, go ahead. All the elements you'll need are in the program above: declare integer variables, enter arithmetic constraints using Lisp-style syntax, and run the solver. How I found the formula: I just ran the program with upper bound of 64, and it gave me (64, -1, -27) :P

Comment: Thank you, @Bubbler, Z3 is sure good at this. (Incidentally it turns out to be Lisp-like enough to allow multiple operands such as `(* 27 a b c)`). Signed, daily Elisp user

Comment: The question says _positive_ integers.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath: No, it doesn't. It says $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @NickMatteo -- I advise you to read the first sentence carefully. "positive integers n" implies that n is a set of positive integers.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath: No, it asks for which positive integers $n$ this holds. There is nothing ambiguous about this phrasing; $n$ is a positive integer. Would it be clearer to you if someone said something like "For which positive integers $n$ is it possible to arrange $n$ dots in a triangle?" Or "For which positive integers $n$ is an $n$-sided regular polygon constructible with compass and straightedge?"

Answer (score 5):

This is only possible if

> the set contains all the same numbers...

Otherwise,

> the AM-GM inequality tells us that the arithmetic mean of a set of distinct, positive, real numbers is strictly greater than the set's geometric mean.

You can get more information on this [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean_Inequality).

Comment: The problem said "integers." Your solution, the AM-GM Inequality, Is based on the assumption of nonnegative real numbers, which renders it inaccurate.

Comment: @KingLogic -- Integers _are_ real numbers and the question says that they are all positive. All positive integers are also nonnegative real numbers, which renders it ***accurate***.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath no, the question says that there has to be a positive number of integers. It doesn't say the integers themselves have to be positive.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime -- While the wording may not be perfect, it is ***quite obvious*** what the author's intent is. I find it quite frustrating, especially when I am the one asking the question, when answerers try to exploit a loophole that is _very clearly not_ what I intended. However, it would be helpful to have MariaLucíaUribe comment on this and let us know.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime -- Also, when taking the geometric mean of something, we tend _not_ to use negative numbers at all (depending on how you learned to do it, taking the geometric mean of a set with a negative number is more or less "undefined"). Therefore, it is okay to assume that the numbers have to be positive _regardless_ of whether or not the OP intended to be that way.

Comment: The very fact that the problem is trivial if the integers are restricted to be positive (as you pointed out and linked to) is itself evidence that that is not in fact that author's intent is. Moreover, the geometric mean of a set of integers *might* be undefined or not well-defined if some are negative, but it's perfectly possible to be defined as well (if the number of integers is odd, for instance).

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Well it is ***quite obvious*** to me that OP meant exactly what they said.